# Implementing Application only API key and secret in servicestack with additional user api keys

Tags: api, authentication, servicestack

So, I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the following authentication in my ServiceStack api.

I want to secure all API calls such that they are only available to applications we define (so semi-private). These applications would be linked to our Company tables. So, lets say we have one table ApplicationKeys linking to Company.

Additionally, we have Users (also linked to a company). These users can also be given an api key to allow specific user related functionality to the app.

How/what is the best way to implement allowing an application to access the api with these two levels of security. 1) endpoints that only require the application to be authenticated. 2) endpoints that require both application and user to be authenticated.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to use the new JWT authorization once 1 or 2 above is validated.

The first thought (and what i'm still working on) is a custom AuthProvider for 1. I'm using ApiAuthProvider as the example. I have to change the type of auth repo so that it only validates against the company and api key. However, even if this first bit works, I'm not sure how to expand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to be problematic to try support multiple API Key Auth providers since the same HTTP bearer token would need to support 2 different API Key providers, one for Company and another for User.

The built-in [ApiKeyAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs) is for User API's key and allows users to authenticate using one of their API Keys.

The Company API Key is different since it's not tied to any user, my initial thoughts is to implement this as a Request Filter restriction instead of trying to integrate it as an AuthProvider which are tied to Users. So I would likely do something like add a custom `X-Company-Key` HTTP Header and add a Request Filter Attribute to validate the company key, e.g:

```
public class ValidateCompanyKeyAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object responseDto)
    {
        var companyKey = req.Headers["X-Company-Key"];
        var company = GetValidCopmany(companyKey);
        if (company == null)
        {
            res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            res.EndRequest();
            return;
        }
        req.Items["company"] = company; //if info needed in Services
    }
}
```

Which you can then generate on your Services, e.g:

```
[ValidateCompanyKey]
public class CompanyServices : Service { ... }
```

An alternative approach may be to create a special "Company" User as a placeholder to hold all company API Keys and maintain which Company the key is for using one of ApiKey table [custom ref data properties](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6d08e73b92b60c9af78ae8c54b874e98210507c8/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs#L45-L47). Of course if you're creating your own custom API Key AuthProvider you can add your own explicit fields. The benefit of this approach is that you can use the same Auth Provider to validate both Users and Company API Keys.

To validate Users via an API Key you can just use the existing `ApiKeyAuthProvider` and ServiceStack's built-in `[Authenticate]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
public class UserServices : Service { ... }
```

Not sure where using JWT's would fit in, a HTTP Request can only contain 1 bearer token and if they're authenticating via API Key they wouldn't be authenticating using a JWT as well. You can of course register both AuthProviders which will allow Users to authenticate using their preference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. First, I misunderstood how the JWT work and realized they are not part of this solution.

I ended up going with a custom request filter and implementing an hmac authentication scheme. I use several custom headers (appId, signature, apiKey). The calling app creates the signature based on a secret key they hold. This allows the server to validate they are who they say they are (to some degree anyway). I also include the user api key in the header rather than using the built in ApiAuthentication. 

I may have to investigate changing that last part though.